# how this solution turn into 1 column and n row ? what i got is 1 row and n column.

Tags: matlab, matrix

```
n=input('n: ')
z=10*pi;
d=z/n;
f=linspace(d,z,n);
disp(f)
```

the display come out :

Columns 1 through 10

```
3.1416    6.2832    9.4248   12.5664   15.7080   18.8496   21.9911   25.1327   28.2743 31.4159
```

i need help to change this into :

3.1416
6.2832
9.4248
12.5664
15.7080
18.8496
21.9911
25.1327
28.2743 
31.4159

Comment: Add a transpose: `f.'`

Comment: 3.1416    6.2832    9.4248   12.5664   15.7080   18.8496   21.9911   25.1327   28.2743 31.4159

Answer (score 0):

Just transpose your result:

```
disp(f.');
```